# How show line in Verbatim environment?

Tags: verbatim

I have a simple Latex code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[2]

\begin{Verbatim}
CPD of G:
╒═════╤═════╤══════╕
│ F   │ F\_0 │ F\_1  │
├─────┼─────┼──────┤
│ G\_0 │ 0.2 │ 0.01 │
├─────┼─────┼──────┤
│ G\_1 │ 0.8 │ 0.99 │
╘═════╧═════╧══════╛

\end{Verbatim}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

After compiling, I get this PDF file
[image]

But I would like to see in my PDF file vertical and horizontal lines, just like in my tex file. Does anyone know the solution and help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could using `|`, `—`, and `+` be a solution?

Comment: Which tex engine are you using?  With `pdflatex` you need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.  With any engine you need a font with these characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pmboxdraw` (Heiko has a solution for almost everything).

I guess you don't really want the backslashes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
CPD of G:
╒═════╤═════╤══════╕
│ F   │ F_0 │ F_1  │
├─────┼─────┼──────┤
│ G_0 │ 0.2 │ 0.01 │
├─────┼─────┼──────┤
│ G_1 │ 0.8 │ 0.99 │
╘═════╧═════╧══════╛
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Sorry for the wrong display here; on my editor it is

[image]